# Disable List Throttling through Server Object Model

Tags: list, runwithelevatedprivileges, resource-throttling

I want to disable list throttling through code so i have written the following code

```
SPList lstBookings = web.Lists.TryGetList("Bookings");
                    lstBookings.EnableThrottling = false;
```

But does this requires the code to be running under elevated privileges, because if i login as a non admin user it gives me an error cannot login.

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: RunWithElevatedPriviledges doesnot solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EnableThrottling seems to require Farm Administrator privileges.  Take a look at the following code:

```
public bool EnableThrottling
{
    get { ... }
    set
    {
        bool nothrottlevalue = !value;
        this.SetListNoThrottle(nothrottlevalue);
    }
} 

internal void SetListNoThrottle(bool nothrottlevalue)
{
    SPSite site = this.ParentWeb.Site;
    if (!site.WebApplication.Farm.CurrentUserIsAdministrator(true))
        SPGlobal.HandleUnauthorizedAccessException(new UnauthorizedAccessException());
    else
        { ... }
}
```

The system account, in turn, has Site Collection Administrator privilege. The SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges allows to run code under the Application Pool identity, which has same Site Collection Administrator privileges on all site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Run this piece of code as the Application Pool identity user:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPriveleges( () => {
     using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
                {
                    var web = site.RootWeb;
                    var lstBookings = web.Lists.TryGetList("Bookings");
                    lstBookings.EnableThrottling = false;
                    lstBookings.Update();
                }
});
```